# Overloading resolution

Tags: c++

As far as I know, when coming to choose between two candidate functions the compiler will prefer the one that its weakest match is stronger.
For example if I have:

```
void boo(int i, char c);  
void boo(double d, int i);
```

for the following code:

```
float f = 1.0;  
char c = 'c';
boo(f,c);
```

the second `boo` should be prefered because its weakest match is promotion while the first one's is standard type conversion.

But when I try to compile it (using gcc), I get:

> error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have an idea. Read that error message over and over again until it becomes clear that C++ standard says this is ambiguous.

Comment: +1 for the developer who wrote the error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your understanding of overload resolution is wrong.  The general
rule (when there are more than one argument) is to choose
a function for which at least one argument is better (it doesn't
matter how much better), and none of the others are worse.  In
other words, the compiler processes each argument separately,
creating a set of "best matches" for it.  After this, it takes
the union of these sets: if the intersection contains exactly one
function, you've won.  Otherwise, it's ambiguous.

Comment: Though I shouldn't be comparing C++ with java but is there any difference b/w their overloading checking process - as above c++ ambiguous code snippet works in Java (promoted types one executes- i.e. `double int` one

Comment: @user2668673 Yes.  The union would almost guarantee ambiguity.

Comment: @sansix And why would one expect two different languages to use the same rules for overloading?  (Actually, I don't know if the rules for overload resolution are different or not.  In Java, the first `boo` cannot be called, and so isn't part of the overload set.)

Comment: *"The general rule is to choose a function for which at least one argument is better and none of the others are worse."* Why do you not say: The general rule is to choose a function for which all argument is better or not worse?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you called the function f.
I think that the overload resolution process is:
**1.** Creating a set of candidate functions. This set of functions includes all of the functions named f that can be accessed from the point where you called f().
**2.** Creating a set of viable functions. This set of functions is a subset of the candidate functions for which the number of parameters of each viable function agrees with the number of arguments you used to call f().
**3.** Chooses the best viable function. **The best viable function is the one whose parameters all have either better or equal-ranked implicit conversion sequences than all of the other viable functions**.
If there are more or less than one (not exactly one), there will be a compilation error.
The following example demonstrates it nicely:

```
class cat
{
public:
    cat(int);
};

void func(int, int, int, cat)
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}
void func(int, int, double, double)
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(1,2,3,4);
}
```

This code generates a compilation error (VS) or warning (g++).

The following will run correctly (print 1):

```
void func(int, int, int, double)
{
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}
void func(int, double, double, double)
{
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        func(1,2,3,4);
}
```